# Why is drawRect not called in the NSView when I programmatically load my window from a storyboard?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, xib, nib

I have a window in my Main.storyboard file that I am trying to load programmatically, and not at application launch. So I have deleted the "Storyboard Entry Point" entirely, and in AppDelegate.swift, I have:

```
let storyBoard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let pauseWindowController = storyBoard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("pauseWindowController")
pauseWindowController.showWindow(self)
```

This seems to work, but when I run the app, I get no window. I added tracing code in my app to follow the progression of events, and I find that my custom NSView subclass is initialized, but drawRect is never called. If I remove the above code above and re-add the Storyboard Entry Point (to point to the window controller), everything works fine.

Here is the result of my `print` calls that I added for tracing, which show the calling class and the method called:

```
(AppDelegate) applicationDidFinishLaunching
(Pause OverlayWindow : NSWindow) Window init
(PauseOverlayView : NSView) View init
(PauseViewController: NSViewController) viewDidLoad
(PauseViewController: NSViewController) viewDidAppear
(PauseViewController: NSViewController) viewWillDisappear
(PauseViewController: NSViewController) viewDidDisappear
```

There should be a line `(PauseOverlayView : NSView) drawRect` line after `viewDidAppear`, and the window should display, but the method is never called. Why?

I have "Visible At Launch" checked in the Storyboard editor for my window. To my understanding, `drawRect` is called if the view is dirty and visible. I imagine it's not visible for some reason, but can't find out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake: I didn't add the `pauseWindowController` property (`var pauseWindowController : NSWindowController!`) to the top of my AppDelegate.swift file. And the code should then become

```
let storyBoard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
pauseWindowController = storyBoard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("pauseWindowController") as! NSWindowController
pauseWindowController.showWindow(self)
```